# Connection String for Connecting Azure SQL Server database in Bot Framework's web.config file

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, botframework

When I tried running the bot in emulator locally with cloud database. It is working.

But it is not working when I host it as a WebApp+SQL in Azure.

End Point Authorization is succeeded When I tried to test the connection in dev.botframework.com, But I'm not getting any reply.

This is the connection string I used

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DBCS" 
         connectionString="Data Source=xxx.database.windows.net,1433;
          Initial Catalog=<dbname>;
          Integrated Security=False; 
          TrustServerCertificate=False;
          User ID=yyy@xxx;
          Password=####;
          Connection Timeout=30" />
    <connectionStrings>
```

Comment: So.. the bot is not working once it's deployed to azure or the bot works but the connection to the DB fails?

Comment: If I run it in the emulator without appid and password but with the azure dbserver. It works fine. Tried doing it with the bot id and key that has been created. And it's not working.

Comment: So the bot is not working in the emulator when you use the bot id and password? Or is it when is deployed? If you comment the interaction with the DB, does it work?

Comment: Yeah..Exactly. The bot is not working if I give appid and password. If remove the app id and password and run in localhost it works fine. I also tried creating a new app service. that also didn't work.

I tried commenting the DB interaction. Still, I didn't get any reply.

Comment: Are you updating the web.config with the botID, app id and app password?

Comment: I never update BotID. It works without that for other apps I published. 

I gave app id and app password.

Comment: The issue is fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed now.

I removed the database connection string from web.config file and configured it in Azure Web App service -> Application settings.

I gave the connection string name I gave in MessageController.cs while creating it through ConfigurationManager.connectionString

```
 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString
```

Also, I updated the BotBuilder from v3.0.0 to v3.0.1 as it had a bug fix with Bot.Connector which I had used in my code.

Both these changes helped.

Comment: Sounds great. If the issue was in the emulator I not sure how adding the connection string in the Azure Web App (that is not being used when running in the emulator) helped to fix the issue. Probably the BotBuilder issue is more related to the behavior you were seeing.

Comment: No. While running in the emulator. I had to use the connection string and while deploying in azure I removed it and published.

Yeah.. could be. bot builder also.

Answer (score 1):

Have you whitelisted the bot's ip address with SQL Server?  If you're not sure what the ip address is, try white listing all ip addresses and see if it helps.

Comment: I've given IP permission from 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255..0